# The multilingual duck

Tags: c#, rubberduck, localization

So, we have this "Rubberduck Settings" window, with a number of "tabs" dedicated to each configurable feature. The "root" tab contains the application's "general settings" and, in the next release, we've found something to put there:

[image: Rubberduck's General Options tab]

The *display language*! Credits to @SimonAndréForsberg and @Vogel612, for the Swedish and German translations respectively.. I did the French translation myself.

The first thing I tried after Simon's *pull request* was merged, was of course trying to switch the display language to Swedish... and that blew up with a `CultureNotFoundException`.

I had to handle the case when a culture wasn't supported/installed on the user's system, so this is how I went about the `DisplayLanguageSetting` class, which gets serialized into the application's xml configuration file:

```
namespace Rubberduck.Settings
{
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class DisplayLanguageSetting
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public DisplayLanguageSetting()
        {
            // serialization constructor
        }

        public DisplayLanguageSetting(string code)
        {
            Code = code;

            CultureInfo culture;
            try
            {
                culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(code);
                _exists = true;
            }
            catch (CultureNotFoundException)
            {
                culture = RubberduckUI.Culture;
                _exists = false;
            }

            _name = RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("Language_" + Code.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper(), culture);
        }

        private readonly string _name;
        private readonly bool _exists;

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string Name { get { return _name; } }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool Exists { get { return _exists; } }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = (DisplayLanguageSetting) obj;
            return Code.Equals(other.Code);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Code.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

---

So the "general settings" tab is only loading the instances where the `Exists` getter is returning `true`. I'm particularly not fond of what I did in the `LoadLanguageList` method... would there be a better way?

```
namespace Rubberduck.UI.Settings
{
    public partial class GeneralSettingsControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly IGeneralConfigService _configService;
        private readonly DisplayLanguageSetting _currentLanguage;

        public GeneralSettingsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TitleLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.SettingsCaption_GeneralSettings;
            LanguageLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.Settings_LanguageLabel;

            LoadLanguageList();
        }

        public GeneralSettingsControl(DisplayLanguageSetting displayLanguage, IGeneralConfigService configService)
            : this()
        {
            _configService = configService;
            _currentLanguage = displayLanguage;
            LanguageList.SelectedItem = displayLanguage;
        }

        public DisplayLanguageSetting SelectedLanguage
        {
            get { return (DisplayLanguageSetting)LanguageList.SelectedItem; }
        }

        private void LoadLanguageList()
        {
            var settings = new[]
            {
                new DisplayLanguageSetting("en-US"),
                new DisplayLanguageSetting("fr-CA"),
                new DisplayLanguageSetting("sv-SV")
            };

            LanguageList.Items.AddRange(settings.Where(item => item.Exists).ToArray());
            LanguageList.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should refactor this to avoid the exception:

```
 public DisplayLanguageSetting(string code)
 {
     Code = code;

     CultureInfo culture;
     try
     {
         culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(code);
         _exists = true;
     }
     catch (CultureNotFoundException)
     {
         culture = RubberduckUI.Culture;
         _exists = false;
     }

     _name = RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("Language_" + Code.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper(), culture);
 }
```

Something like this should help:

```
private static bool TryGetCulture(string cultureName, out CultureInfo result)
{
    result = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals(cultureName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    return result != null;
}
```

You'll notice that I've changed the name of the parameter to culture name as I think of code as being the numerical code [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx).

So:

```
public DisplayLanguageSetting(string code)
{
    Code = code;

    CultureInfo culture;
    _exists = TryGetCulture(code, out culture);
    if (!_exists)
    {
        culture = RubberDuckUI.Culture;
    }

    _name = RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("Language_" + Code.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper(), culture);
}
```

As an aside, `CultureInfo` has a `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` which can replace your substring.

Comment: I like this a lot.

Answer (score 6):

- I would group all of your properties together. Right now you have `Code` separated from the other properties by the ctors.
- When overriding `Equals`, it's important to be sure that it ***can't*** throw an exception. The current implementation can throw an InvalidCastException.

  > ```
  >     public override bool Equals(object obj)
  >     {
  >         var other = (DisplayLanguageSetting) obj;
  >         return Code.Equals(other.Code);
  >     }
  > ```

  A proper implementation would look something more like this.

  ```
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
      var other = obj as DisplayLanguageSetting;

      if (other == null)
          return false;

      return Code.Equals(other.Code);
  }
  ```
- I don't much care for the control either.

  > ```
  >  public partial class GeneralSettingsControl : UserControl
  > ```

  That's more or less all I need to see to know I don't care for it. How's that? Because that's all I need to know about the class to know that business logic is being put into the code behind instead of a presenter class. We've got a "smart" form on our hands here. Invert the control. This should be implementing an interface that exposes properties for the different view elements.

  ```
  public interface IGeneralSettingsView
  {
      DisplayLanguageSetting CurrentSetting {get; set;}
      IList<DisplayLanguageSetting> {get; set;}
  }
  ```

  Note that once you do this, the class no longer needs a Configuration Service at all. (The presenter will still need it though).

Comment: We've got a "smart UI" all over the configuration code...

Comment: Yeah. I know. That was some of the earliest code I wrote.

Comment: BTW the `Equals` implementation would be better written as a single return statement (including the soft-cast): `return other != null && Code.Equals(other.Code);`